# Irreducible representations of Heisenberg group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Lately, I've been struggling with the following problem. Let $H$ be the 3 dimensional [Heisenberg group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group) and let $\rho:H\to\text{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ be a irreducible representation. Show that $n=1$.

I do not have any concrete idea where to begin, so any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An irreducible representation $H\rightarrow GL(V)$ induces an irreducible representation on the Lie algebra level. By Lie's theorem, every irreducible representation of a complex solvable Lie algebra is $1$-dimensional. The Heisenberg Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is nilpotent, hence solvable.